# Angular8 | User Authencation

Tags: mysql, angular, crud, angular8, web-sql

I use **Angular8** and **make a content system**. I am pulling the data **with MySQL** and decided to use websql since I could not establish a direct connection with the server, then I did not find it appropriate in this idea. Is there a place where I can hold the data, where can I keep it?

Comment: you can store the data inside LocalStorage or SessionStorage

Comment: I also used them, but the data is changeable, something to prevent

Comment: You can use ngrx/store to store data locally in a redux style fashion.